# Flutter setState() not working for widget in GridView

Tags: flutter, setstate

I have a very basic widget that won't rebuild when calling setState. I've searched and tried everything I can think of. I must be overlooking something. If I set breakpoints in Android studio I can see that the value does change but it's not rebuilt or rerendered or its overridden by its invocation.

Heres the widget in question.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NewestCommunityImagesWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  String id;
  String image;
  String userSlug;
  String username;
  int likes;
  // String created_at;
  bool is_favorited;
  Function upvoteCommunityImages;
  Function flagCommunityImages;

  NewestCommunityImagesWidget({
    this.id,
    this.image,
    this.userSlug,
    this.username,
    this.is_favorited,
    this.upvoteCommunityImages,
    this.flagCommunityImages,
    this.likes,
  });

  @override
  _NewestCommunityImagesWidgetState createState() =>
      _NewestCommunityImagesWidgetState();
}

class _NewestCommunityImagesWidgetState
    extends State<NewestCommunityImagesWidget>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Card(
      child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
          child: Column(children: [
            Image.network(widget.image),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
              child: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                    widget.is_favorited
                        ? Icons.favorite
                        : Icons.favorite_border,
                    color: widget.is_favorited ? Colors.red : Colors.black),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    widget.is_favorited = !widget.is_favorited;
                  });
                  widget.upvoteCommunityImages();
                },
              ),
            )
          ])),
    );
  }
}
```

Here's how I render the widgets.

```
GridView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                  itemCount: community_images.length,
                  itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => NewestCommunityImagesWidget(
                      id: community_images[index].id.toString(),
                      image: community_images[index].image,
                      userSlug: community_images[index].userSlug,
                      username: community_images[index].username,
                      // created_at: community_images[index].created_at,
                      likes: community_images[index].likes,
                      is_favorited: community_images[index].favorited,
                      upvoteCommunityImages: () {
                        upvoteCommunityImage(
                            community_images[index].id.toString());
                      },
                      flagCommunityImages: () {
                        flagCommunityImage(
                            context, community_images[index].id.toString());
                      }),
                  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                      crossAxisCount: 2,
                      crossAxisSpacing: 1,
                      mainAxisSpacing: 1,
                      childAspectRatio: 20 / 30),
                )
```

I have a similar comments widget with the same functionality that works fine... Thanks for your set of extra eyes, let me know if there's other information you need to debug this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `Function` to change the `favorite` state, like `upvoteCommunityImages` and `flagCommunityImages` Functions

> ```
> Function(bool newFavoriteState) changeFavotireState;
> ```

```
//in NewestCommunityImagesWidget widget
IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
                widget.is_favorited
                    ? Icons.favorite
                    : Icons.favorite_border,
                color: widget.is_favorited ? Colors.red : Colors.black),
            onPressed: () { 
              widget.is_favorited = !widget.is_favorited;
              widget.changeFavotireState(widget.is_favorited); 
              widget.upvoteCommunityImages();
            },
          ),

// outside 
NewestCommunityImagesWidget(changeFavotireState:(newFavoriteState){
    setState(){
       community_images[index].favorited = newFavoriteState;
    };
 });
```

Leave the value that you are passing in the constructor as it is, as default value.

**The reason it does not change outside is: `is_favorited` become refer to another place in the memory**